# How to disable autocomplete code statements in code editor?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

Every time I type `if` and press the space bar, Delphi completes it with `if True then` and a new empty line above.

Is there a way to remove **this** "autocomplete" feature or at least edit it to not create the new line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's called a *live template*, and you can edit the list of live templates in the [template window](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Templates_Window), from the View menu.

Find the template you don't like, select it, and click the "remove template code" button.

Comment: Yes, I could edit it and remove the unnecessary `empty line`, which was there because a word wrap in the XML text.

Comment: Then save all, exit the IDE and go back.   +1, this was bothering me also on a reinstall.

Answer (score 12):

From the *Tools | Options | Editor Options | Code Insight* menu, deselect the Auto complete check box under Code template completion.

[image]

Once you disable template auto complete then you need to manually invoke the template if you want it. Do that with <kbd>CTRL+J</kbd>.

Comment: for Delphi 10.4, it's under *Tools | Options | User Interface | Editor | Source*,  hidden in the  *Code Insight* tab

Comment: Note: In the try of disabling autocomplete, I just switched "Code insight manager" to "none". This will enable some of the auto-completions, so make sure you keep "Delphi (....)" selected there.

Answer (score 0):

Since the default location for the live code templates is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\16.0\ObjRepos\en\Code_Templates` (for XE8, similar for other editions), you will need to change the permissions on this directory (and its subdirectories) in order to edit or add live templates. Default permissions do not include write permission to this directory.